# Facebook OpenGraph Dialog appears for 2 seconds and disappears

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

My Facebook login is working properly, I ahve a button and within its click I have the following code:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putString("og:type", "books.book")
    .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
    .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
    .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
    .build();


ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType("books.read")
    .putObject("book", object)
    .build();

ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
    .setAction(action)
    .build();

ShareDialog.show(getActivity(), content);
```

But unfortunately and due to the pathetic Facebok Documentation I am not able to debug properly, I dont get any logs. The dialog appears for 2 seconds and before I can press anything it disappears. What could be the cause here?

Somehow, I ahve managed this:

```
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030): Exception during service
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 2500 [message]: Unknown path components: /books.read [extra]: 
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:104)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:137)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:234)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:185)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.JsonResponseHandler.a(JsonResponseHandler.java:34)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.b(ApiResponseHandler.java:91)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:54)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:29)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:951)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:293)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:225)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:92)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor$Dispatcher.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:1176)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor$Dispatcher.run(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:1155)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.common.executors.ConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(ConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:308)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:38)
04-24 16:49:37.417: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(26030):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-24 16:49:37.612: W/ActivityManager(727): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@1c546d46
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the action type to be "books.read", but really it's "books.reads". See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/books.reads/

Comment: Let me check with that!

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936840/cant-import-request-session-and-response-facebook-sdk-4-0