# Cant import Request, Session and response Facebook SDK 4.0. [Egregious Documentation]

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am using the Facebook SDK 4.0 and I want to post on users wall using the OpenGraph API.

I have defined the Action as:

- Celebrating

The object as

- Milestone

Now when in the Facebook Dev console I click on get code and switch to Android I get the following snippet:

```
Request request = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/objects/friendsampleapp:milestone",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST
);

Response response = request.executeAndWait();
```

Here I cant get options to import Response, Request and Session.

I get an option to import `com.facebook.login.LoginClient.Request;` but with a red squiggly line which on hover says: `The type com.facebook.login.LoginClient is not visible`.

The point worth to note here is that in the same activity, my login is working fine so this is not an issue with importing the Facebook Library.

In the [Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x) Facebook mentions:

> Session Removed - AccessToken, LoginManager and CallbackManager
>   classes supercede and replace functionality in the Session class.

I wonder if Facebook expects me to dream of how to interface their API with my code when its all broken, releasing SDK's at this rate, is not helping anyone.

I also tried to log a bug report with Facebook but however seems for facebook, that is broken too!

### Edit:

Digging deeper I have changed the above code to:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
                GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),"me/objects/friendsampleapp:milestone",params, HttpMethod.POST);
                GraphResponse response = request.executeAndWait();


                Bundle params1 = new Bundle();
                params1.putString("milestone", "http://samples.ogp.me/812890225461181");

                GraphRequest request1 = new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),"me/friendsampleapp:celebrating",params,HttpMethod.POST);
                GraphResponse response1 = request.executeAndWait();
```

But however I am confused, what next?

Comment: I am not even able to fill a bug report on Facebook, this code seems obsolete with their new SDK. Facebook why do you suck?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @p.streef what do you not understand in the question?

Comment: @p.streef which part of the question is not clear to you?

Comment: Before the last edit the solution to the question "what's next" was actually in the question. But I guess you want to post a graph story without the sharing dialog?

Comment: I separated that part so that you could understand it properly and might be someone else lands on this page and gets confused. So I thought to separate the question from the answer.

Comment: Did you already have a 3.x app that you were trying to upgrade to 4.x? If so, what documents did you follow? I would like to know how we can improve our docs, and feedback is appreciated. For example, the upgrade guide you linked to also linked to how to do Login in v4, as well as explicitly documenting that Request is now GraphRequest. If that was not enough, how can we make the docs better for everyone here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final thing I have come up with and apparently, it does work:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                        .putString("og:type", "friendsampleapp:milestone")
                        .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
                        .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")

                        .build();


                // Create an action
                ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                        .setActionType("friendsampleapp:celebrating")
                        .putObject("milestone", object)
                        .build();


                // Create the content
                ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                        .setPreviewPropertyName("milestone")
                        .setAction(action)
                        .build();




                ShareDialog.show(getActivity(), content);
```

Comment: What are other types used other than "badge" with setPreviewPropertyName(...)?

Answer (score 0):

Because the facebook docs are terrible. In the upgrade guide they show how to make a request

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.optString("id"));
                }
            }
    }).executeAsync();
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

Comment: Bro, this is hilarious facebook is turning out to be more of a fish market than an actual Dev company.

Comment: Actually facebook docs are not just terrible but they are pathetic. They create confusion in place of resolving them.

Comment: Hello WizKid, I have mentioned that I am not able to file a bug report. Its broken! Lol are you a facebook Dev? The link you provided is broken too! I cant stop laughing!

Comment: it´s https://developers.facebook.com/bugs - everyone makes mistakes sometimes. would have been easy to find out by just putting "facebook bugs" into google, it´s the first result ;)

Comment: @luschin, mate try to file a bug report on the 'CORRECT' link. the feature is broken! I do agree that mistakes are a part of life and I am open to everyone who helps or does not help. You could have checked the time I last said 'I am not able to file a bug report' and the time WizKid gave away this link. Having said that, cheers the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you're not able to create a bug? If you go to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/all/, you'll see that plenty of people are/were able to create bugs in the last few days. Let's try to figure out why you couldn't.